# How to compare against a null element in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have a program where I need to store the results in an arraylist:-

```
public class ReseedingDBRandomElements {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {

            // getting the field Keyword from the csv
            String csvfile="/Users/dray/Downloads/ReseedingDBRandomKeywords.csv";

            BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
            StringTokenizer st = null;
            String line="";
            int linenumber=0;
            int columnnumber;

            // initializing the parameter for each column
            int free = 0;
            int free1 = 0;



            // create the ArrayList

            ArrayList<String> Keyword = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> Alternate = new ArrayList<String>();


            // reading through the csv file
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                linenumber++;
                columnnumber = 0;

                st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    columnnumber++;
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                    if("Keyword".equals(token)){
                        free=columnnumber;
                        System.out.println("The value of free :"+free);
                    }else if ("Alternate".equals(token)){
                        free1=columnnumber;
                        System.out.println("The value of free1 :"+free1);
                    }

                    if(linenumber>1){

                        if (columnnumber==free)
                        {
                            Keyword.add(token);
                        }else if (columnnumber==free1){
                            Alternate.add(token);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // converting the keyword ArrayList to an array
            String[] keyword = Keyword.toArray(new String[Keyword.size()]);
            for(int i=0;i<keyword.length;i++){
                System.out.println(" The value of the keyword is :"+keyword[i]);
            }

            // converting the alternate ArrayList to an array
            String[] alternate = Alternate.toArray(new String[Alternate.size()]);
            for(int i=0;i<alternate.length;i++){
                System.out.println("The value of the alternate is :"+alternate[i]);
            }

            ArrayList<String> AlternateNew = new ArrayList<String>();


             for(int i=1;i<keyword.length;i++){
            if(keyword[i].equals(keyword[i-1])){
                AlternateNew.add(alternate[i-1]);
            }else if(!(keyword[i]==(keyword[i-1]))){
                AlternateNew.add(alternate[i]);
            }
        }


            String[] alternatenew = AlternateNew.toArray(new String[AlternateNew.size()]);
            System.out.println("The length of the array is :"+alternatenew.length);
            for(int i=0;i<alternatenew.length;i++){
                System.out.println("the value of the alternatenew :"+alternatenew[i]);
            }




        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("there is an error :"+e);
        }

    }
}
```

The following is the csv file

```
Keyword,Alternate
ego kit,baby doll
ego kit,garage park
ego kit,random beats
galaxy tab,venus
galaxy tab,earth
galaxy tab,sun
```

What I am trying to do is compare elements and store it in an arraylist and display the results, but when last element is getting compared i.e 'galaxy tab' is getting compared to an empty field after last 'galaxy tab', it is not storing the previous result in the arraylist which is 'sun'

The following is the result of the program :

```
The value of the alternate is :baby doll
The value of the alternate is :garage park
The value of the alternate is :random beats
The value of the alternate is :venus
The value of the alternate is :earth
```

The last element is not getting stored in the arraylist.

Do not understand why? New to Java programming.

Comment: Your code could be significantly shortened and simplified if all you want to do is the read the `String` after the `,` in every line.

Comment: I just tried your program and I think I'm getting the result you expect, which makes me think maybe your input file isn't terminated properly (maybe it doesn't end in a newline?).  Try putting `System.out.println("read line: "+line)` after `readLine()` and make sure all your input lines are getting read.  Also, this won't work: `keyword[i]==(keyword[i-1])`.  Don't ever compare strings with `==`, use `keyword[i].equals(keyword[i-1])`.

Comment: after i couldnt find an error, i run your code on my pc and it worked for me, i get all 6 values...

Comment: there is a purpose to doing so, actually I want to store it in two different array lists one for ego kit and the other for galaxy tab where the array list will contain only elements for ego kit and the other for galaxy tab. I do not know exactly how to store the elements in two different array lists using the for loop, and also why the last element 'sun' is not getting added to the arraylist?

Comment: I think you should ask "How do I split this CSV file into multiple lists where each list shares the same keyword." I don't know if this is homework, but it seems to me that you're in over your head. I don't want to do your work for you, but I think people will help guide you in the right direction. What programming experience do you have? I would read the whole file in, sort based on keyword, then create a list for every unique keyword, then place items in each list with the same keyword.

Comment: You probably want a `Map` so that you will have an `ArrayList<String>` for each keyword, i.e. `Map<String,ArrayList<String>>`.  Here's a tutorial on maps: [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)`.  As for why the last element isn't getting added, please try my earlier suggestion, I think there's a problem with the file input.

Comment: If you want to store some strings for your keywords you could use a HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>. and btw like i said before, your code works for me, i get all values

Comment: i have made necessary changes in the logic, and I do not want to split the CSV, I want to randomly select an element from the same set of ArrayList,one for 'ego kit' and the other for 'baby doll', one element from arraylist1 and the other from arraylist2 and display them, so that is why I want two different arraylists. It is a real time problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section has a few problems also present throughout

```
        AlternateNew.add(alternate[0]);
        for(int i=1;i<keyword.length;i++){
            if(keyword[i]==(keyword[i-1])){
                AlternateNew.add(alternate[i]);
            }else if(!(keyword[i]==(keyword[i-1]))){
                AlternateNew.add(alternate[i]);
            }
        }
```

1. The naming convention in Java is to start with a lowercase letter for a variable name (unless it is a constant), which is why object `AlternateNew` is highlighted as if it were a class name.
2. The `else if` block tests the opposite of the same condition as its `if`. You could comment out `if(!(keyword[i]==(keyword[i-1]))`, delete, or replace it with a more readable reminder comment, and the result would be the same.
3. `AlternateNew.add(alternate[i]);` happens regardless of this condition, in either branch of the `if`, so either remove the `if` statement entirely or fix some typo.

As for your actual [edit: original] question, I can't find anything wrong. Are you sure you didn't forget to save the csv file? I ran it using a text file and got output contrary to your post!

Comment: @ clwhisk : I have posted the new code for everyone's reference, which does not give me the desired answer.

Comment: Please rewrite the section where you populate AlternatNew. You still have convoluted logic and a comparison of strings using ==. Hint: you should only need to test one condition within the loop, and need only one line about adding.